# Ubuntu 20.04 now 21.10 reverts to CLI on it's own

Tags: boot, command-line, 20.04, gui, 21.10

[image]

The gui on my laptop shuts down on its own and I'm taken to this screen.
This happens when I stop a key binding after pressing ctrl ket only(usually while opening terminal).
But today it happened when I opened gnome boxes and just changed the resolution  on my linux mint download, which I have previously done without any problem.

I tried searching this problem but couldn't find any relevent article.

Why does this happen.
Is there a way to login to the graphical environment without rebooting?